# JS: how do I match a parameter input to a function to a global object by name?

Tags: javascript

I have a html form (dropdown) which selects a country, e.g. "UK". This value is then input into a function, which I want to show the type of country in HTML by matching it to global variable of the same name:

```
var UK = { country: 'UK', type: 'European' }
function showCountry(arg1){
  document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = arg1.type;
}
```

The above doesn't work for some reason. Clearly, using the same parameter name as a global object in the hope that the two will match doesn't work. I'm wondering: 
1. what's the underlying reason, 
2. how can I match the parameter input to a global variable of the same name?

Comment: please create a jsfiddle about the problem.

Comment: Try using `window[arg1].type` if your global variable is truly global.

Comment: I don't follow... could you post more code to put in context what you are asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to have an object of keys and values corresponding to the country code that is passed into the function. What you are doing in your example is searching for `.type` of `arg1` which is a string not a variable. That's why it doesn't work.

```
var countries = {
    UK: {
        country: 'UK',
        type: 'European'
    }
};

function showCountry(arg1) {
    document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = countries[arg1].type;
}
```